Kamal mysql setup with Ruby on Rails
I'm not able to complete a production deployment with Kamal2 and Ruby on Rails 8.0.0.pre2 using the video provided https://kamal-deploy.org
When I run kamal setup it creates the db accessory without any issues, as well as the kamal proxy. It fails at the very end on the final build check for the app docker container.
Releasing the deploy lock...
  Finished all in 90.4 seconds
  ERROR (SSHKit::Command::Failed): Exception while executing on host 192.168.xxx.xxx: docker exit status: 1
docker stdout: Nothing written
docker stderr: Error: target failed to become healthy

When inspecting the deployment logs there is the following:
2024-11-08T14:31:42.688568367Z Tasks: TOP => db:prepare
2024-11-08T14:31:42.688572580Z (See full trace by running task with --trace)
2024-11-08T14:31:44.208156934Z bin/rails aborted!
2024-11-08T14:31:44.208182929Z ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished: Can't connect to server on '127.0.0.1' (115) (ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished)

I have listed the DB_HOST: app-db in the deploy.yml file
In the database.yml file I have the host: <%= ENV.fetch("DB_ HOST") { "127.0.0.1" } %>
It seems like the kamal setup is not using the DB_HOST: app-db to setup the docker container network connection?
I can post my complete deploy.yml and database.yml files if needed.
UPDATE:
Here is my deploy.yml file
# Name of your application. Used to uniquely configure containers.
service: app

# Name of the container image.
image: user/app

# Deploy to these servers.
servers:
  web:
    - 192.168.x.xxx
  # job:
  #   hosts:
  #     - 192.168.0.1
  #   cmd: bin/jobs

# Enable SSL auto certification via Let's Encrypt and allow for multiple apps on a single web server.
# Remove this section when using multiple web servers and ensure you terminate SSL at your load balancer.
#
# Note: If using Cloudflare, set encryption mode in SSL/TLS setting to "Full" to enable CF-to-app encryption.
proxy:
  ssl: false
  host: app.domain.local

# Credentials for your image host.
registry:
  # Specify the registry server, if you're not using Docker Hub
  # server: registry.digitalocean.com / ghcr.io / ...
  username: user

  # Always use an access token rather than real password when possible.
  password:
    - KAMAL_REGISTRY_PASSWORD

# Inject ENV variables into containers (secrets come from .kamal/secrets).
env:
  secret:
    - RAILS_MASTER_KEY
    - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
  clear:
    # Run the Solid Queue Supervisor inside the web server's Puma process to do jobs.
    # When you start using multiple servers, you should split out job processing to a dedicated machine.
    SOLID_QUEUE_IN_PUMA: true

    # Set number of processes dedicated to Solid Queue (default: 1)
    # JOB_CONCURRENCY: 3

    # Set number of cores available to the application on each server (default: 1).
    # WEB_CONCURRENCY: 2

    # Match this to any external database server to configure Active Record correctly
    # Use app-db for a db accessory server on same machine via local kamal docker network.
    DB_HOST: app-db

    # Log everything from Rails
    RAILS_LOG_LEVEL: debug

# Aliases are triggered with "bin/kamal <alias>". You can overwrite arguments on invocation:
# "bin/kamal logs -r job" will tail logs from the first server in the job section.
aliases:
  console: app exec --interactive --reuse "bin/rails console"
  shell: app exec --interactive --reuse "bash"
  logs: app logs -f
  dbc: app exec --interactive --reuse "bin/rails dbconsole"


# Use a persistent storage volume for sqlite database files and local Active Storage files.
# Recommended to change this to a mounted volume path that is backed up off server.
volumes:
  - "app_storage:/rails/storage"


# Bridge fingerprinted assets, like JS and CSS, between versions to avoid
# hitting 404 on in-flight requests. Combines all files from new and old
# version inside the asset_path.
asset_path: /rails/public/assets

# Configure the image builder.
builder:
  arch: amd64

  # # Build image via remote server (useful for faster amd64 builds on arm64 computers)
  # remote: ssh://docker@docker-builder-server
  #
  # # Pass arguments and secrets to the Docker build process
  # args:
  #   RUBY_VERSION: 3.3.5
  # secrets:
  #   - GITHUB_TOKEN
  #   - RAILS_MASTER_KEY

# Use a different ssh user than root
# ssh:
#   user: app

# Use accessory services (secrets come from .kamal/secrets).
accessories:
  db:
    image: mysql:latest
    host: 192.168.x.xxx
    # Change to 3306 to expose port to the world instead of just local network.
    port: "127.0.0.1:3306:3306"
    env:
      clear:
        MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: '%'
      secret:
        - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
    files:
      # - config/mysql/production.cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf
      - db/production.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/setup.sql
    directories:
      - data:/var/lib/mysql
#   redis:
#     image: redis:7.0
#     host: 192.168.0.2
#     port: 6379
#     directories:
#       - data:/data


root@app:~# docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                         COMMAND                  CREATED       STATUS       PORTS                                                                      NAMES
b3c70139a8a4   basecamp/kamal-proxy:v0.8.2   "kamal-proxy run"        2 hours ago   Up 2 hours   0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, :::80->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp, :::443->443/tcp   kamal-proxy
709816c42ee7   mysql:latest                  "docker-entrypoint.s…"   2 hours ago   Up 2 hours   127.0.0.1:3306->3306/tcp, 33060/tcp                                        app-db


Were you able to resolve this error? I am stuck at the same error and cant find a working solution to it.
